# What spacing is needed between aircraft parking stands?

Tags: airport-design

I'm doing a project where I have to design an apron for a general aviation airport (ICAO type 2B). The airplanes have to park in angled nose-in parking, or angled nose-out parking.

What is the required separation between two stands? I think that the dimensions of one stand depend on the turning radius of the airplane that is supposed to use the stand, but I don't know where to find this angle for every airplane...

I'm looking for any data or other relevant information.

Comment: I know I've parked 172s where there was less than 12" from wing-tip to wing-tip of adjacent planes.   It took two pushers and two wing-walkers to put planes in safely.

Comment: I think most GA aircraft can lock the brake on one wheel and pivot around it.  Also, when I park I almost always shut down the engine and push the plane into the spot.  See also [this list of airplane sizes](https://www.bifold.com/airplane-size-chart.php)

Comment: Sure, let's have [some spacing](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/03/15/2841C6CC00000578-3066229-American_sports_reporter_Levan_Reid_posted_this_image_on_Twitter-m-26_1430663722801.jpg) now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Aerodrome Standards manual](http://www.icao.int/safety/implementation/library/manual%20aerodrome%20stds.pdf), which is based on [ICAO Annex 14](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/ICAO_Annexes_and_Doc_Series), gives the following values:

> **Clearance distances on aircraft stands**
>
> 3.12.6 An aircraft stand shall provide the following minimum clearances between an aircraft using the stand and any adjacent building, aircraft on another stand and other objects:
>
> Code Letter | Clearance
>
> A | 3 m
>
> B | 3 m
>
> C | 4.5 m
>
> D | 7.5 m
>
> E | 7.5 m
>
> F | 7.5 m

A references for the ICAO code letter categories is available here: http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/ICAO_Aerodrome_Reference_Code

Comment: Yes, in this case the distance between two planes is 3 meters. But the distance between two stands isn't 3m+wingspan+3m, because the plane has to park with its own propulsion, so has to do a 180º turn in this space.

Comment: To be fair, you did ask for the width _between_ stands, not the width of individual stands

Comment: @oriolflvi While J. Hougaard's comment might appear to be nitpicking, on Stack Exchange, we generally do aim to answer *the exact question that was asked*. If you realize *before* getting any answers that what you asked wasn't quite what you *meant* to ask, it's common to edit the question to fix that. As this stands, with an upvoted answer, I would encourage you to simply ask a new question, and in it, be more specific about what exactly you are looking for. There's no shame in linking to this and saying "I asked this other question too, but it wasn't exactly what I meant because XYZ".

Comment: Even us old-timers on the network get it wrong on occasion, realizing that we asked a perfectly valid question, got perfectly valid answers to it, but that it turned out that *the question we asked wasn't what we wanted to ask*. In that case, it's often best to simply accept that what you asked wasn't what you meant to ask, treat the question as asking what it actually asked instead of what you meant to ask (so vote, accept etc. based on that), and ask a new, better question drawing from the experience thus gained, highlighting the differences between the two questions (to avoid dupe votes).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to explain better the problem and what i'm looking for. I never saw this forum and I've seen that it's very interesting and a useful tool, so thank you for explain me better how it works.